# Adding strings in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, function, string-concatenation

Can any one help me in knowing  the equivalent syntax for

```
SET @xx = 'data'+ CURDATE() +'.txt'`
```

...in MySQL? Basically I want to join a string and a sys function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to CAST date as CHAR

```
SELECT CONCAT(  'data', CAST( CURDATE( ) AS CHAR ) ,  '.txt' )
```